# Why is it called "Time series"?

Tags: sequences-and-series, time-series

Wikipedia's (informal) definition if a time series is

"A time series is a series of data points indexed (or listed or graphed) in time order. Most commonly, a time series is a sequence taken at successive equally spaced points in time."

As *sequence* is defined as an indexed set of objects (often numbers), where the order of the objects is non-trivial, it would make more sense to me if it were called **time sequence**. As a series is (informally) defined as a sum of an infinite sequence.

So does anyone know the origin of the name "time series"? Is it just random, or is there a reason to the madness?

Comment: "Series" has other meanings in different contexts.

Comment: Presumably the name comes not from the meaning of *series* in real analysis as "the sum of an infinite sequence" but from the the broader meaning in English as "a number of things or events of the same class coming one after another in spatial or temporal succession" (Merriam-Webster).

Comment: Note that most uses of time series are in applied math, which isn't as concerned with mathematical jargon.